# How to remove warning .ts file is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have recently migrated from Angular 9 to 12 and getting below warning while building the application:

```
basic-app.component.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused
basic-app.module.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused
basic-app.main.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused
```

My application consists of two projects: basic and advanced. So, when I am trying to build basic application, its shows me warning for the advanced files and when I am building advanced, its shows warning for the basic files.

I have separate main.ts, app-module.ts and app-component.ts for each application

**My folder structure:**

```
app
--->Basic
    --->basic-main.ts
    --->basic-app.module.ts
    --->basic-app.component.ts
--->Advanced
   --->advanced-main.ts
   --->advanced-app.module.ts
   --->advanced-app.component.ts
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "../Client",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "app/advanced/advanced-test.ts",
    "app/basic/basic-test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec_HZ.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./app/advanced/advanced-main.ts",
    "./app/basic/basic-main.ts",
    "./polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**angular.json**

```
"projects": {
    "Basic": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "index": "Client/index.html",
            "main": "Client/app/basic/basic-main.ts",
            "polyfills": "Client/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "Client/tsconfig.app.json",....
}}}},
"Advanced": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "index": "Client/index.html",
            "main": "Client/app/advanced/advanced-main.ts",
            "polyfills": "Client/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "Client/tsconfig.app.json",,....
}}}}
```

Comment: I think you should use two tsconfig.app.json, one for each 'version' of your app. So can configure things independently, like excluded files.